# Why it has Trace?

Tags: linear-algebra

> The operator tr : $T_1^1 (V ) \rightarrow R$ is just the trace of $F$ when it is considered as an endomorphism of $V$ . Since the trace of an endomorphism is basis-independent.

I am very confused with this statement because to my understanding, $T_1^1$ is $V^* \otimes V$. How can it be a matrix and have trace?

Comment: Asking how a matrix could have a trace is very strange, considering the [definition of *trace*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trace_(linear_algebra)). Are you asking how elements of $V^*\otimes V$ are supposed to be seen as matrices? In general there is a correspondence between maps $U\to V$, $1\to U^*\otimes V$, $U\otimes V^*\to 1$, $V^*\to U^*$. (In other words, the four $\hom$ spaces are naturally isomorphic.)

Comment: What is $F$? What is $R$? What is $V$? What is $T^1_1(V)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When $V$ is finite-dimensional, there is a canonical isomorphism $V^\ast \otimes V \cong L(V)$ given by sending the $(1,1)$-tensor $a \otimes b$ to the linear transformation $v \mapsto a(v)b$ on $V$. Thus, the trace of a $(1,1)$-tensor can be defined as the trace of the corresponding linear transformation, which in turn can be computed as the trace of the matrix of that linear transformation with respect to any basis of $V$.

An equivalent way to view the trace on $T^1_1(V)$ is directly as the map $T^1_1(V) = V^\ast \otimes V \to F$ defined by $a \otimes b \mapsto a(b)$.

Comment: That's really helpful. Thanks. But what is the canonical isomorphism for $V^* \otimes V \cong L(V)$ for higher dimensions? Namely, for $T^k_l$? Thank you very much!

Comment: @user83036: What is $T^k_l$? Something like $(V^*)^{\otimes k}\otimes V^{\otimes l}$?

Comment: Yes @Brad. Thanks!